# jquery sum and subtract prices from checkbox with initial price

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have an initial value `$8.90` and the idea is to add a extra fee if a checkbox is selected. Each checkbox has the price in a data-price value, the problem goes when I click on a second checkbox. It should add the fee to the current value:

**LIVE SCRIPT:** http://jsfiddle.net/NF7x9/

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var subt_value = parseFloat($('#subt0').text());
var start_price = parseFloat($('#subt0').attr('data-original'));

        $("#ser1, #ser2").click(function(){

            var sub_total = 0
            var extra_fee = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')/1.12).toFixed(2);


            $(this).each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    var sub_total = subt_value + parseFloat(extra_fee);
                    $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(sub_total).toFixed(2));
                }else{
                    $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(start_price).toFixed(2));
                }
            });


        });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<label id="subt0" data-original="8.90">8.90</label>

<input name="service1" type="checkbox" id="ser1" data-price="1" value="1" title="Service 1" />
<input name="service2" type="checkbox" id="ser2" data-price="5" value="1" title="Service 2" />
```

**RESULT:**

Starts with **$8.90**. If I select the checkbox with `ID=ser2` the price changes to `13.36` Now if I check the box with `ID=ser1` the total is `$9.79` when it should be `14.25`

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Perhaps try to rephrase your question?

Comment: ok i edited my post with more details, but in the LIVE EXAMPLE you can see my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This is now a much better question. Perhaps now someone will be able to answer it for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just check each time one of the checkboxes is clicked and calculate from the start value.

```
 var subt_value = parseFloat($('#subt0').text());
 var start_price = parseFloat($('#subt0').attr('data-original'));

    $("#ser1, #ser2").click(function(){
        var amountToAdd = 0.0;
        // check each button to see if it has a clicked state.
        $("#ser1, #ser2").each(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                amountToAdd += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
            }
        });

        $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(amountToAdd+start_price).toFixed(2));
   });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NF7x9/1/

Comment: how can i divide the data-price /1.12?